# Ver a que pod estoy accediendo al ingresar a una url (MInikube)

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

Tengo un deployment creado y un servicio NodePort, este deployment tiene 3 replicaset de una app (una api) cuando hago un describe del servicio puedo ver que cada pod tiene un endpoint en este caso:

172.17.0.5:15400
172.17.0.6:15400
172.17.0.7:15400

O sea cada una de esas ip pega en cada pod que levanto el replicaset.

AHora , si ingreso a la ulr con el ip generado por el nodeport, como puedo saber a que pod le estoy pegando cada vez que actualizo la pagina con F5?

Estoy usando un minikube local

Comment: Que quieres que muestre? El nombre, IP?

Comment: El nombre del pod, el ip q tiene, cualquier cosa, solo quiero saber q donde estoy yendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Usa la downwardapi](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api)

Con variables de entorno

```
...
  containers:
  - name: x
    env:
    - name: POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    - name: POD_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.podIP
```

En la app accesa a la variables de entorno $POD_NAME y $POD_IP